# Can I launch electron-updater updates when my app closes?

Tags: typescript, electron, auto-update, electron-updater

I have implemented electron updater's auto updates in an app and it was awesome.

But the app checks for updates at startup in the main electron process.

So, I wish to know; is there a way to install updates when the app is closed in the back-ground ? Or at least deffer updates to when the user closes the app.

I read the docs and I found awesome tips about updating while the app is running but I haven't found anything yet about this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The `auto-updater` is embedded into your electron app and the updater will be running as a `child process` of your electron app. You know, the child process will be terminated following the termination of main process.

So with default `auto-updater`, you can't achieve your goal.
Not impossible, but you should build your own `auto-updater` for your app.

But consider this, if you are going to do like this for every electron app then this means every electron app requires their exclusive auto-updater...

I'd say, this is not the right way for auto-updater.